# Strange behaviour of std::cout after function call

Tags: c++

I have a simple program that set unsigned int variable. Well, I have one problem. `std::cout` works fine until `InputCLI` is called.

First time program prints line when debugger reaches line that contain `std::cout`

> ```c++
> std::cout << "debugNumber" << debugNumber;
> ```

After `InputCLI` call program prints lines only with **\n** untill it reaches `std::cin` operator. Whats wrong?

I'm coding in Eclipse (Linux). The moment before `std::cin >> wait;` was executed:

[image]

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

unsigned int InputCLI(unsigned int& x);
int main() {
    int wait;
    unsigned int debugNumber = 0;
    std::cout << "debugNumber " << debugNumber;
    std::cout << "Enter debug number\n";
    InputCLI(debugNumber);
    std::cout << "debugNumber\n";
    std::cout << "debugNumber " << debugNumber;
    if (debugNumber == 6) {
        std::cout << "bubu";
    }
    std::cin >> wait;
    return 0;
}

unsigned int InputCLI(unsigned int& x) {
    if (std::cin >> x, std::cin.fail()) {
        if (std::cin.bad() || std::cin.eof())
            return -1;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits < std::streamsize > ::max(), '\n');
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show example session, with actual output, and one session with expected output?

Comment: I have added one link in my problem description

Comment: So, your problem is that you dont see : 'debugNumber 9' in output? If so, then have you tried adding `<< std::endl` ?

Comment: "_program prints lines only with \n untill it reaches std::cin operator_" Sounds like line buffering, try flushing with `std::endl` or manually.

Comment: If I dont add \n or std::endl std::cout will buffer data?

Comment: @maxi AFAIR exact buffering behavior is implementation defined, but generally yeah, you can expect some kind of buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I dont add \n or std::endl std::cout will buffer data?

Yes, exactly.

`std::flush` explicitly flushes the stream. `'\n'` on its own doesn't do any flushing at the C++ level, but may trigger a flush at a lower level. `std::endl` prints a `'\n'` then does a `std::flush`.

Certainly, without any of those, you can't realistically expect a flush before your `std::cin`.

Comment: `\n` cannot trigger a flush at a lower level because C++ is required not to pass it along to anywhere else until a `flush`. Also, it's worth noting that `<< std::flush` is also a valid way to express flushing, and more expository than `endl`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's not required to but that doesn't mean it won't. There are multiple layers of buffering going on.

Comment: I said "required not to," not "not required to." If the text is stuck in the first buffer, it's not going anywhere else.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Oh, is it really? It can't flush arbitrarily?

Comment: It never gets an opportunity to. The abstract base `std::basic_streambuf` does the buffering, and the `fstream` (or whatever) subclass only regains control on `overflow()`. The user can opt for *no* buffering, and that's the default for `std::cerr`, but that's a bit different.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Why can't the `std::basic_streambuf` flush arbitrarily?

Comment: Because it's specified not to. It fills the buffer it's given, anything else would be broken and would probably cause the concrete implementation to flush uninitialized data.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: What if the buffer is filled before `std::flush` is called? I'm trying to demonstrate that a `std::flush`/`std::endl` is not the only circumstance under which data is flushed to the OS (or whatever the next layer down is).

Comment: `flush` invokes `sync` which is a different virtual method from `overflow`. A concrete subclass need not support `sync` at all and could just throw. `streambuf` is a bit crazy, but it's not allowed to be arbitrary, and thank God for that.

Comment: Yes, filling the buffer will cause a flush, but that's not related to a newline as the answer suggests. It's triggered by whatever character overflowed the buffer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It is related but not in the way you've interpreted. If a block of arbitrary characters ends up being flushed by the IOStream, because the buffer was filled, then those characters are sent to the next layer down. That layer may then choose to flush on any `\n` found within that block of bytes if it is using line buffering (as many terminals do by default). In this scenario the final outcome, as observed by the user, is a flush to screen at the point that a `\n` is written.

Comment: _(cont.)_ Though, yes, this not "reliable" because it will only occur if the IOStream buffer had been maxed out in the first place. That's where the word "may" comes in, in the relevant passage in my answer.

Comment: Have you even referred to the standard? No, there `streambuf` is not allowed to modify the pointers which define the buffer before calling `overflow`. There's no maybe about it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Huh? I didn't say it was! Are you not aware that IOStream semantics are not the only mechanism at play here? I'm starting to wonder...

Comment: `streambuf` takes bytes to be written and puts them directly in the buffer. There is no point for customization and no latitude for implementation variance. No other layer of implementation has access to the data until `overflow` or manual `flush` occurs. So no, there is no other mechanism at play.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Overflow is precisely what I am talking about. I never said anything about customisation. I can't tell whether you're being deliberately obtuse.

Comment: You mean that `\n` may be flushed normally from C++, after a few kilobytes, and then subsequently cause a flush of a line-oriented output device. Yes, but that's certainly not happening in OP's code which only outputs a few bytes. As for obtuseness, you quietly changed your argument at "It is related but not in the way you've interpreted." There was nothing to indicate you were talking about something completely different at that point.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's what I've been talking about quite clearly the entire time, and it's what my answer says. At no stage did I say it was the OP's problem: again, my answer clearly says that this is what is _not_ happening. I'll leave you now to read it again because I won't argue against a strawman or a non sequitur. I have better things to do! (marginally) :)

Comment: "Oh, is it really? It can't flush arbitrarily?" — Keep the topic straight.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: You're misunderstanding again, and I don't see why. It's pretty clear. Contrary to my understanding, which I spelt out, and which you finally agreed to five hours ago, your early comments indicated that data in an IOStream could _only_ be flushed to OS when `std::flush` were called (which is obviously false when you consider the buffer filling up). So, my response to that was an incredulous "oh, is it really?" Please stop being so obtuse. This is not complicated.

Comment: OP example will not overflow so I didn't mention that irrelevant case. Try playing with `std::cerr` and you will likely find that what is unbuffered at the C++ level is likely unbuffered the rest of the way up the stack too. You're insisting that hypothetical situations are realistic. I'm being realistic, not obtuse.

Comment: I'm not "insisting" anything. We're talking about how streams work. At least, I am. I'm going to leave this thread be now: have a good day!